# What is LDAP enumeration?

Tags: redhat, ldap, sssd

I have been working with implementing LDAP in our servers. We are using SSSD instead of nscd/nslcd to communicate with the LDAP server.

One of the options in SSSD is enumeration. Enabling it solved an issue we were having while implementing the LDAP-client on RHEL.

- Can somebody explain more clearly what LDAP enumeration means?
- How does enabling/disabling LDAP enumeration affect the environment?
- Is this an LDAP-specific or a SSSD-specific term?

I was unable to find much information around this feature, so hopefully this Serverfault question can help other people as well.

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/chap-SSSD_User_Guide-Configuring_Domains.html:

> Enumeration means that the entire set of available users and groups on the remote source is cached on the local machine. When enumeration is disabled, users and groups are only cached as they are requested. For performance reasons, it is recommended that you disable enumeration for domains with many users and groups.